# How can I select the specific window I want from a list of CMD windows with the same name with AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to make a AutoHotKey script that will send command to a certain CMD window, but I am having problems with selecting the needed window, because I am running at least 3-4 CMD windows and their titles all start with "C:\Window\System32\cmd.exe" so at most I just looping trough the windows one by one.

How can I select !the specific window I want from a list of CMD windows with the same name ?

[image]

Most of the cases those are the CMDs I use and I want to target the first one (Upper left corner) which has the most generic name.

Comment: Can you tell us how do you know whats the right window? This will help in finding the method that lets the script select the right cmd window...

Comment: Well thats the problem - in theory all the windows are the same since they all are CMD windows. The right window is the one that I have firstly ran the command I want (which is the run the project build). I guess closing the CMD window after I build my project and make an AHK script that opens a CMD and runs the build command is a solution... but I don't think that would be a good one, therefore I ask the question above.

Comment: All the cmd windows will have their own window ID aka hwnd when you have the hwnd of a window you just use that with `ahk_id %hwnd%` in the command or functions title parameter, but you still need a way for the script to know whats the right window it Can be the Z-order or the size or the time it was created or something else...

Answer (score 2):

You could try starting it from AHK and retrive the ID automatically from there ...

You also could try to build a function which "teaches" which CMD to use ... this would require to click in them CMD window once after it appeared ... basically your AHK script then have to read the UID of this window.

> WinGet
>
> Retrieves the specified window's unique ID, process ID, process name, or a list of its controls. It can also retrieve a list of all windows matching the specified criteria.
>
> `WinGet, OutputVar [, Cmd, WinTitle, WinText, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText]`

e.g.: `WinGet, OutputVar , ID , A` would retrieve the ahk_id of the active window

But without further details it is hard to tell what you really need.

Comment: Well I like the solution with the click on the window this would work, since I'll need to do that once and then only use the mapped key to repeat it. I am unsure on how exactly to get the ID, will try and see if I understand your example on it (I'm fairly new to AHK)

Comment: I just added an image for you to see what I mean. I need to select the most upper left CMD window. As I said doing something like click after I open it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can distinguish different cmd.exe windows with AutoHotkey.

But you can use other command line software which will allow to distinguish different command line sessions with AutoHotkey. For example, [here](http://www.nextofwindows.com/4-better-windows-console-tools-alternatives-to-windows-built-in-command-prompt/) and [here](http://www.guidingtech.com/23974/command-prompt-alternatives/) are some other command line software. Other software are easily findable with [google](https://www.google.ge/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=alternative%20command%20line&spell=1). Look at there screenshots, most of them have tabs for different command line sessions. You can switch between different tabs by using AutoHotkey GUI automation commands.

Comment: Cmd windows are different just like all other windows, the hwnd of the cmd windows Can be used but you still need to know what window you need. Lots of ways to do that!

Answer (score 0):

when initializing the windows you could use the title command.

```
Run, %comspec% /k cd c:\ && title MyWindow 1 && tasklist
winwait,MyWindow 1
WinMove,MyWindow 1,,20,20
Run, %comspec% /k cd c:\ && title MyWindow 2
winwait,MyWindow 2
WinMove,MyWindow 2,,20,365
ControlSend,,taskkill /pid ` ,MyWindow 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"... Мне нужно выбрать самое верхнее левое окно CMD."
```

Тогда надо что-то типа:

```
; SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; (если надо) Заголовок окна должен содержать контекст.
WinGet, hListCMD , List, % "ahk_exe " cmd.exe ; Список ID всех окон CMD
IF !hListCMD0
   ExitApp ; Закрыть скрипт если нету окон CMD
Loop % hListCMD0 ; Перебрать все найденные окна
   WinGetPos, CMD%A_Index%_X, CMD%A_Index%_Y, , 
   , % "ahk_id " hListCMD%A_Index% ; Узнать координаты для каждого
```

Потом - сравнивать координаты, что-бы найти "самое верхнее левое". Напр:

```
Min_X := CMD1_X
Min_Y := CMD1_Y
Loop % hListCMD0
   {
   IF (CMD%A_Index%_X < Min_X) Or (CMD%A_Index%_Y < Min_Y)
      {
      Min_X := CMD%A_Index%_X
      Min_Y := CMD%A_Index%_Y
      hMinCMD := hListCMD%A_Index% ; или так hMinCMD := hListCMD[A_Index]
      } ; IF
   } ; Loop
```

**hMinCMD** - (HWND/Handle/ID) содержит идентификатор искомого окна. Далее активизировать его и послать команды.  Напр:

```
WinActivate, % "ahk_id " hMinCMD
Send, {Home}Diskpart /? ; Вывести правку по Diskpart
```

Ещё можно поиграться встроенной функцией - **Value := Min(Number1 [, Number2, ...])** для нахождения наименьшего значения перечисленных переменных.

Удачи всем.

Comment: Please, translate your answer to english.

Comment: Don't post answers in foreign languages. You need to Edit your answer. You clearly understand the question in English, edit your answer in it too.